# Does Haskell have a strict Set container?

Tags: haskell, set, containers, strictness

If we look at the [`containers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) package. They have [`Data.Map.Strict`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html), but there is no equivalent `Data.Set.Strict`. Would it make sense for it to exist?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Set` is strict. In a same way as both `Map.Lazy` and `Map.Strict` are strict in the *key*. E.g from the `Data.Map.Lazy` module:

> This module satisfies the following strictness property:
>
> - Key arguments are evaluated to WHNF

The reason is quite obvious: to make any decisions (i.e. something else than always return `EQ`) the `compare` have to evaluate the arguments to at least a WHNF (to separate different constructors in a sum type, e.g.)